# JWKS with TypeScript,Next.js and zeroDev, custom hosted JWKSendpoint

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt, jwk

I am trying to make an App with Next.js, TypeScript, JWKS and zeroDev using JWKS endpoints. I can code and decode the JWT using private and public keys with (RSA256) fine, but I am confused what data to put in the JWKS endpoint file, because from what I have seen in various tutorials and documents, they are not putting the public key in the JWKS but rather it's modulus and I am not sure how to use the modulus to decode/verify the JWT.
The tutorial I was following used 2 npm packages, but they both don't have typescript support and have very low number of downloads so I am trying not to use them,
Would appreciate help in understanding this.

I am hosting the JWKS in my own application in a public folder

Tried putting various fields of JWKS endpoint into the JWT online website to verify token signature but none of them work, Public key also says invalid signature but when I use it in code it verifies ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Originally the question was about logic but I managed to find a way to solve the issue , using a different approach. 

Hosting my own JWK now